# Select and update query in same and find duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

everyone! I'm trying to write a query to find the duplicates of content and set all duplicates except original article (original article will defined by the counter (*if counter of original post greater than all other duplicates counter, it's a original*) and set to active=0 in database.

```
DB achitecture{id, title (varchar), description(varchar), img(varchar), active(int)}
```

The following query for find the duplicates

```
  SELECT posts.title, posts.counter, posts.id
  FROM posts
  INNER JOIN (
  SELECT title
  FROM posts
  GROUP BY title
  HAVING count(title) > 1
  ) duplicates ON posts.title = duplicates.title
  ORDER BY posts.title;
```

I need to set active = 0 for a duplicates
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can readily turn this into an `UPDATE` with `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE posts INNER JOIN
       (SELECT title, MAX(counter) as maxcounter
        FROM posts
        GROUP BY title
        HAVING count(title) > 1
       ) duplicates
       ON posts.title = duplicates.title AND posts.counter < maxcounter
    set posts.active = 0;
```